# Validate fieldset on button click before moving onto other fieldset

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, forms

I have a multi-step form which comprises of three `fieldsets`.

I have a button named `next` which on click, shows the next `fieldset` (it animates it in).

Before this next `fieldset` is shown, on `next` click I want to run a check to see if the user has completed all the fields in the current `fieldset`. Essentially complete this `fieldset` before moving onto another.

The pseudo I'm trying to achieve is:

- User has none of the required fields filled in and clicks the `next` button.
- alerts user that none of the fields in this fieldset are filled in.
- Next fieldset as a result isn't shown until required fields are filled in.
- User now completed required fields.
- On `next` click, the next `fieldset` can now be shown.

**What I've tried:**

```
function checkInputs() {
  var isValid = true;
  $('fieldset').filter('[required]').each(function() {
    if ($(this).val() === '') {
      // $('#confirm').prop('disabled', true)
      isValid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });
  if(isValid) {$('#confirm').prop('disabled', false)}
  return isValid;
}

$('#confirm').click(function() {
  alert(checkInputs());
});
```

In my demo below, you'll see I'm running this function on `.next` click. In the demo, if the firstname and address field are left blank (those are required fields), clicking next alerts true, which is incorrect.

As a result, it loads in the next fieldset.

**Full demo:**

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets
  var left, opacity, scale;
  var animating;

  /*************************************************/
  // CHECK IF FIELDS ARE FILLED IN BEFORE NEXT CLICK
  /**************************************************/

  function checkInputs() {
    var isValid = true;
    $('fieldset').filter('[required]').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() === '') {
        // $('#confirm').prop('disabled', true)
        isValid = false;
        return false;
      }
    });
    if (isValid) {
      $('#confirm').prop('disabled', false)
    }
    return isValid;
  }

  $('#confirm').click(function() {
    alert(checkInputs());
  });


  /***********************************************/
  // ONCLICK NEXT BUTTON, ANIMATE IN NEXT FIELDSET
  /***********************************************/

  $(".next").click(function() {

    checkInputs();

    if (checkInputs() == false) {
      console.log("fill required");
    } else {
      if (animating) return false;
      animating = true;
      current_fs = $(this).parent();
      next_fs = $(this).parent().next();

      next_fs.show();
      current_fs.animate({
        opacity: 0
      }, {
        step: function(now, mx) {
          scale = 1 - (1 - now) * 0.2;
          left = (now * 50) + "%";
          opacity = 1 - now;
          current_fs.css({
            'transform': 'scale(' + scale + ')',
            'position': 'absolute'
          });
          next_fs.css({
            'left': left,
            'opacity': opacity
          });
        },
        duration: 800,
        complete: function() {
          current_fs.hide();
          animating = false;
        },
        easing: 'easeInOutBack'
      });
    } // else close
  });




  /*********************************/


});
```

```css
.form {
  min-height: 800px;
  user-select: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.form form#rsvpForm {
  width: 600px;
  margin: 50px auto;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}
.form form#rsvpForm fieldset {
  background: white;
  border: 0 none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 15px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 60px 50px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  display: block !important;
}
.form form#rsvpForm fieldset:not(:first-of-type) {
  opacity: 0;
}
.form form#rsvpForm input,
.form form#rsvpForm textarea {
  padding: 15px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type='text/javascript' src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js?ver=5.3.2'></script>

<div class="form" id="rsvp-form">

  <form id="rsvpForm" action="" method="post">

    <!-- fieldset 1 -->
    <fieldset>
      <input type="text" name="fname" placeholder="First name*" required />
      <textarea name="address" placeholder="Address*" required></textarea>
      <input type="button" id="confirm" name="next" class="next" value="Next" />
    </fieldset>

    <!-- fieldset 2 -->
    <fieldset>
      <textarea name="other" placeholder="Enter your note here ..."></textarea>
      <input type="submit" name="submit" class="submit" value="Submit" />
    </fieldset>



  </form>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the problem is with this line of code:

```
$('fieldset').filter('[required]').each(function() {
  // your code here
})
```

because what `filter` does is, it filters all the `fieldset` based on what selector you pass. So, it looks for all `fieldset`s that have attribute `required`, which are none. So it doesn't get into the loop.

What you need is this:

```
$('fieldset').find('[required]').each(function() {
  //your code here
})
```

`find` finds all the elements with what selector you pass, which in your case is `required` and `each` will then iterate over it.

More about [find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) and [filter()](https://api.jquery.com/filter/).

working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rohitravikalra/hc36nxsr/4/).